# How can I make my model fields optional in Django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to follow the full example at the bottom of

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

In my model I have modified to the following

```
date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
```

However when I try register a user I still get the following error message:

```
date_of_birth <ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul>
```

In what other places do I need to make date_of_birth optional?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You would have to add `blank=True` as well in field definition.

```
date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

From [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) doc

> If the model field has blank=True, then required is set to False on the form field. Otherwise, required=True.

Don't forget to reset and sync DB again after changing this.

Comment: What happens if blank=True but you leave null as false? (assuming false is the default)