# Can not assign None to Django DateTimeField()

Tags: python, django

Can I judge this is a bug?
DateTimeField is inherited from DateField and it can be an optional

I have read:
[How to make Django's DateTimeField optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351619/how-to-make-djangos-datetimefield-optional)
[How can I make my model fields optional in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16828315/how-can-i-make-my-model-fields-optional-in-django)

models.py

```
class Circuit(SoftDeletionModel):
    ...
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    expiry_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

At terminal

```
$ python -B manage.py makemigrations --settings=config.settings.docker
apps.circuits is ready
apps.circuits_networkdevices is ready
apps.core is ready
apps.customers is ready
apps.networkdevices is ready
apps.networkscripts is ready
apps.portal is ready
apps.bod is ready
apps.scheduler is ready
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'updated_datetime' to circuit without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> None
Migrations for 'circuits':
  0022_auto_20161102_1714.py:
    - Add field expiry_datetime to circuit
    - Add field updated_datetime to circuit
```

migration_file.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.9 on 2016-11-02 10:14
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('circuits', '0021_auto_20161102_1653'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='circuit',
            name='expiry_datetime',
            field=models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=None, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='circuit',
            name='updated_datetime',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, default=None),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Error Django:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column "updated_datetime" contains null values
```

Error Postgres:

```
postgres_1       | ERROR:  column "expiry_datetime" contains null values
postgres_1       | STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE "circuits_circuit" ADD COLUMN "expiry_datetime" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
```

Spec:

```
In [2]: django.VERSION
Out[2]: (1, 9, 9, 'final', 0)

$ python --version
Python 3.5.1

> SELECT version();
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| version                                                                                  |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| PostgreSQL 9.5.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2, 64-bit |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misunderstand what [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) does

> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved.

You'll still need to specify a valid default or allow for null values with `null=True`

Comment: As an alternative to allowing `null` you can also use `auto_now_add` which will set the current date/time when a new row is inserted.

Comment: Could be useful also to add "blank=True" for the admin interface.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign `None` to `updated_datetime` because you have not set `null=True` in the model.

You have created a migration that tells django what to do if it encounters existing rows in the `circuit` table when adding the field but that is not the same as being able to do it.

The default value asked for by the migration does not check that value is allowed to be used, it's trusting you to know what you are doing.

In your migration use `datetime.now()` rather than `None`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer it is an new knowledge for me, but Sayse response first then I have to put correct mark on his reply

Comment: I'm glad you have a solution to your problem. But, just so you know for future questions you may ask, Stackoverflow does not require you to accept the _first_ answer posted. You should accept the _best_ answer for your question. I'm not saying Sayse's answer is not worthy or incorrect, it's just because you said "Sayse response **first** then I have to put correct mark on his reply" (my emphasis on **first**)

Comment: Arh sorry for that next time I will put correct on the best informative one. I read your post and then understand the his post. Therefore with this situation I accept, but later time I will accept the one answer that I can follow first

Comment: I used timezone.now during migration

Answer (score 1):

**DateField.auto_now**

Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved.

**DateField.auto_now_add**

Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created.

You can use anyone:

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

or

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

or

```
from django.utils import timezone
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to delete all migrations and erase your database data too and do migrations again
2. excute commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake
```